# Why disassemble multi-thread binary is hard?

Tags: disassembly, disassemblers, multi-process

Why disassemble multi-thread binary is hard? I also know that some obfuscation techniques are to create unnecessary threads. But why reverse engineering multi-thread program is hard.

Answer (score 3):

The technique you are referring to is called 'nanomites'. I would advise you the reading of this [article](https://doar-e.github.io/blog/2014/10/11/taiming-a-wild-nanomite-protected-mips-binary-with-symbolic-execution-no-such-crackme/) as a full example of reverse of a nanomite crack-me.

Never the less, the problem of multi-thread or multi-process reverse-engineering is that in place of one sequence of events (with only one program), you have to follow in parallel multiple programs that interact (possibly in a non-deterministic way) with each others. It raise up exponentially the complexity of the reverse-engineering process.

#### References

- [Taming a wild nanomite-protected MIPS binary with symbolic execution: No Such Crackme](https://doar-e.github.io/blog/2014/10/11/taiming-a-wild-nanomite-protected-mips-binary-with-symbolic-execution-no-such-crackme/) .
- [Unpackme I am Famous](http://blog.w4kfu.com/post/Unpackme_I_am_Famous).